# Chrome Extension: Is it possible to find out if 'debugger' statement exists?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I was wondering if it is possible programmatically to use Chrome Extension to figure out if a given script being executed in a tab contains 'debugger' statements.

I read in an another post on Stackoverflow that this is not possible via pure JavaScript.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Is `given script` a script on some page in a wild wild web? You can programmatically download the code or access a `<script>` element  directly and use string matching if the code isn't obfuscated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `content_script.js` use this code:

```
var actualCode = '(' + function() {
    var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length ; i++){
       if(nodes[i].text.indexOf('debugger') > -1){
           alert("Debugger present");
           break;
      }
    }
} + ')();';


    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.textContent = actualCode;
    (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
```